# How to call a function with return values with Swift Timer?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, timer

All tutorials I read only deals functions without a return type, e.g.,

```swift
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func fireTimer() {
    print("Timer fired!")
    runCount += 1

    if runCount == 3 {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

In the example above, `fireTimer`  has no return values. What if my function is `fireTimer()->some Struct`, how can I obtain the return value? Thanks!

Comment: You can't. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
    let result = self.fireTimer() 
    // Then do whatever you want with your result.
}
```